# Названия стран по-русски

Tags: ономастика

Почему в русском языке названия государств не звучат на языке оригинала, пример - Китай (Чжун), Япония (Нихон), не является ли это нарушением правил? Белорусы требуют от русских говорить Беларусь согласно ОКСМ.

Comment: Какие правила, по-вашему, нарушены?

Comment: Имеют ли белорусы право на требование? У них претензии к русскому языку, видимо. Они хотят его подправить?

Comment: @shampar, Вопрос этот чрезвычайно интересный, но, к сожалению, выходит за рамки этого сайта. Что делать,. если один и тот же язык является государственным в разных странах?  С английским, например, пришли к тому, что в словарях равноправно существуют варианты, принятые в британском и американском английском.

Comment: Тема, если именно об этом речь в вопросе, серьёзная. Только ею ли заинтересовался автор? Сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

> не является ли это нарушением правил?

Нет. Единых правил нет, поэтому и нарушать тут нечего.

"На языке оригинала" ничего звучать не может уже потому, что в языках разная фонетика, невозможно воспроизвести все звуки "оригинала". Но определяющим в выборе названия является традиция. Это применимо вообще ко всем странам и языкам. В дополнение к названным могу вспомнить, например, Дойчланд, Суоми, Мадьяроршаг, Хайястан, Сарктвелло, Бхаратистан, аль-Миср, Шкиперия... Много вы без справочников узнаете названий этих безусловно знакомых вам стран?

Но иногда, правда, в вопрос вмешивается политика. Государства меняют названия, названия же стран (вне политического аспекта) остаются. И тут нужен максимально взвешенный подход. Можно, например, понять, почему Цейлон стал Шри Ланкой, Верхняя Вольта - Буркина Фассо, А Берег Слоновой Гости - Кот-д-Ивуаром. 
Но вот Кыргызстан - это, простите, ни в какие ворота не лезет, голая политика.

> Белорусы требуют он русских говорить Беларусь согласно ОКСМ.

А вот это вопрос сложный. На мой вкус, в этом названии нет ничего предосудительного, но писаться по-русски оно должно Белорусь, как это изредка делалось до обретения страной независимости. Беларусь - нарушение принципов русской орфографии. Приходится считаться, коли уж так захотелось властям предержащим. Но, принимая такое решение, явно не просчитали языковые последствия. Появились "беларусы" и "беларуский язык", что даже сейчас никакими правилами не предписано.

Подробно - можете поискать и на этом ресурсе, и на других. Материалов по этому поводу много, в том числе и моего авторства.